# Being aware of duplicate calendar events

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add events to the calendar on Android. Adding is working fine, but each time I call the add event method, it creates duplicates. I've tried to update events, and delete all events with a specific title, but no success.

My import method:

```
public static boolean importToCalendar(@NonNull Activity activity, CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return false;

        removeExistingEvent(activity, calendarEvent);

        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            event.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
        else
            event.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

        event.put(Events.TITLE, calendarEvent.getTitle());
        event.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, calendarEvent.getDescription());
        event.put(Events.DTSTART, calendarEvent.getStartTime());
        event.put(Events.DTEND, calendarEvent.getEndTime());
        event.put(Events.STATUS, calendarEvent.getEventStatus());
        event.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, calendarEvent.getHasAlarm());
        event.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

        Uri uri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, event);
        Log.d("calendar: ", "inserted " + uri);

//        long eventId = getLastEventId(uri);
        return true;
    }
```

where removeExistingEvent is:

```
public static void removeExistingEvent(@NonNull Activity activity, CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {
        String[] proj =
                new String[]{
                        CalendarContract.Instances._ID,
                        CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN,
                        CalendarContract.Instances.END,
                        CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID};

        ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = CalendarContract.Instances.query(
                contentResolver,
                proj,
                calendarEvent.getStartTime(),
                calendarEvent.getEndTime(),
                calendarEvent.getTitle());

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, id);
            contentResolver.delete(eventUri, null, null);
            Log.d("calendar: ", "deleted" + id);
        }
    }
```

The log says:

> W/ContentResolver: Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar)
>   06-15 12:03:22.872 9934-9934/com.ptr D/calendar:: deleted482
>   06-15 12:03:22.899 6312-6325/com.android.providers.calendar W/ContentResolver: Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar)
>   06-15 12:03:22.918 9934-9934/com.ptr D/calendar:: inserted content://com.android.calendar/events/299

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting by title, try deleting by eventId. You can try that in the [Events: delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete).

```
service.events().delete(calendarId='primary', eventId='eventId').execute()
```